# Simplify dragging an excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula =$A$1... that I would like to change to =$A$2 as I drag it to the right 
or change to =$B$1 as I drag it down.

Is there a trick to do this? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so (at least in any direct way), you are trying to automatically transpose while dragging. At first I thought that you were talking about column absolute or row absolute, but this is something different

Comment: Absolute references (with $ signs) will NEVER change when dragging. What is your goal here? To have a formula that returns the value of the cell, but transposed?

Comment: The reason for the $$ is that i want the formula to stay $A$1 as I drag it down and I want it to not go to $B$# as I drag it to the right.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a formula like this

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$3,COLUMN(A1),ROW(A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I figured that there was *some* way of achieving this indirectly (hence the parenthetical in my comment above). It is nice to see it worked out. The gif is also cool.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for the feedback. I use SnagIt for these animated screenshots.

Comment: Very cool visual. Thanks for the help! I think another solution would be to just transpose the A column and reference it in the formula. Thanks again